# How to hide link to the top of a region in VS2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Suppose I create a region in Visual Studio.

[image]

When this region gets longer and the top of the region is no longer visible in the top of the screen, Visual Studio provides a link next to the end of the region to take you back to the start of the region.

[image]

I don't like this link. I sometimes accidentally click on it and get lost, and it is extra words I don't want. Is there a setting to turn this off? Where is it?

Comment: VS2013 (C# editor) does not do this. Check your installed extensions, disabling them one by one until you find the culprit. Once you know which extension does this, you'll know where to look for the option.

Comment: Thank you, I have found the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the extension, VSCommands. You can turn off this setting by going into the VSCommands settings, IDE Enhancements, Text Editor, and uncheck "Enable Code Block End Tagger".